# How can I upload my sketch to Arduino Nano?

Tags: c++, arduino, nano

Device: *Arduino Nano*

Processor: *ATmega328p*

Programmer: *AVRISP mkII*

Port: *COM5 USB 2.0*

When I'm trying to upload sketch, it's saying

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xec
```

And it's trying to do this 10 times, and then saying

```
avrdude done.  Thank you.

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

Comment: It might be better to ask that on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: try Processor: ATmega328p (Old bootloader)

Comment: @Juraj I have already solved this.

Comment: how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possibility for this message can be so much, that it is impossible to say why this happens.

Just a note:
If you are uploading it with the normal COM, you don't need to write the programmer type. It is used if you are uploading it with the ISP interface.

So the questions are:
- are you using a programmer for the Arduino nano? Why?

The nano has already a bootloader, so you can just upload your sketch over the COM port.

Some times, the serial port isn't able to send the reset signal. Some times it is just not connected. If this is the case, you can press the "RESET" button when you see it is trying to upload the sketch.

Some times, you just have a clone. So don't have to select a nano but a mini pro if you want upload your sketch without errors.

In this case, I think you are just trying to upload the sketch with a programmer even if you don't have one connected... But I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, but what is "RESET" button? Where it is?

Comment: There is only 1 button on your Arduino nano: https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-nano this is the reset button. If the Arduino starts with this pin set, it starts as programming mode. If not, you can get the message like "programmer is not responding".

Comment: @LetGameヅ, why did you accept the answer?

Comment: @Juraj downvoted and accepted ;) Probably because it wasn't an Arduino. But the answer was not wrong, so I don't know why downvoted.

Comment: the downvote is by me. Nano has auto reset and I don't understand why do you mention Mini

Comment: Every Arduino has an auto reset. And it is connected to the serial. Some times you just have RX and TX connected to it (maybe the serial does not have the DTR line active) and so you have to press the button manually. I always reported the nano, never the mini. On ebay you can buy some Nano boards - v3.0, but you have to set "mini pro" if you want programming them.

Comment: you can select "Old bootloader" for Nano instead of selecting Mini Pro